# In OS X, I want to change to a non-standard keyboard shortcut for switching spaces

Tags: macos, keyboard, spaces, expose

In System Preferences > Expose and Spaces > Spaces Tab > to switch between spaces, there is a drop down list that allows you to select a modifier key and the arrows. The arrows are so far away from the rest of the keyboard! I want to bind to the vim keys (h, j, k, l) for (left, down, up, and right). On my Ubuntu machine, I push the equivalent of command-option-j to go down a space. Does anyone know how to change to a non-standard keyboard shortcut on OS X?

(I ran across a post that details how to change the modifiers, but still uses the arrow keys. This is not what I'm trying to do. [Custom keyboard shortcuts to change active Spaces desktop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3880/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-to-change-active-spaces-desktop))

Comment: @Nate: I think matthepavkov has your answer, but also check out KeyRemap4MacBook for it's vi modes.

Comment: @calavera - KeyRemap4MacBook allowed me to accomplish the feat. Under Vi Mode I selected the option for Command_L+hjkl, which magically works in tandem with the standard modifier from before. I wish there were a native way to do this, but this does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: great, once again the awesome keyremap4macbook saves the day :P  i switched my comment to an answer.

Comment: Somebody actually likes the vim keys? :O i didn't think that was possible

Answer (score 3):

Go to *System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts*. Then, on the left side, select *Exposé & Spaces*. On the right side you will see the current keyboard shortcuts for Exposé and Spaces. If you double click on the shortcut command (literally double click `^1` for instance) you will be able to change this to whatever you want. Just do the key-combo you want to use.

So, once you double-click on the shortcut, it'll show it as editable. Then, press the keys you want the short cut to be, all at once, for instance press `Apple` and `J` at the same time, and it'll change the shortcut.

Comment: thanks - this is close to what I wanted, except that the "switch between spaces" option doesn't appear on that list.

Comment: @zm1th Are you in 10.6? I tried this and it worked perfectly. Once you're in the *Keyboard Shortcuts*, click on *Exposé & Spaces* which appears on the left. On the right, you'll see a list of items for *Exposé* and also for *Spaces*. Is *Spaces* not shown there?

Comment: yeah, there are shortcuts for selecting a specific space, but there are not shortcuts for switching between spaces.

Comment: @zm1th Correct. There doesn't seem to be a way to change from the arrow keys to something else. There may be a command line way, but I'm not sure. You can also use the `fn + F8` to bring up all four spaces, and then click the one you want.

Comment: Update: There are now shortcuts for "Move left a space" and "Move right a space". I don't know when they added these, but I think it was a while back.

Answer (score 1):

I think matthepavkov has your answer, but also check out [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) for it's vi modes.